# Caching JPA entities in Memcached

Tags: primefaces, memcached, jpa-2.0

I am retrieving a list of objects from the database data that is seldom updated and thus saving it in Memcached for better performance so that subsequent calls for the list of objects can be retrieved from cache instead of the database.

The list of objects are countries that are displayed to the users using Primefaces Autocomplete component (each time the user types something, there is a asynchronous call to the server) and the library allows the use of a list of custom objects instead of a list of String.

Should I be converting it into a value object instead of using the entity object?, or should I be converting it to a list of String, or just stick to what I am using - entities itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next:

```
String jpql = "SELECT c.name FROM Country c";
List<String> list = em.createQuery(jpql, String.class)
                      .getResultList();
for (String str : list) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```